# Visual artifacts on screen, but not visible on screenshot (Ubuntu 17.10, dual monitor)

Tags: screen, visual-artifacts

I just installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my PC. I run a dual monitor setup and on my main screen the screen looks pretty bad. On my other screen everything looks great.

The strange thing is that when I take a screenshot and look at it on my second monitor, there's no blocks at all.

I took a picture with my phone to illustrate:

[image]

On the screenshot, everything looks good:

[image]

I have a AMD Radeon rx580 and a Ryzen 5 1600. The main monitor (having issues) is an Ilyama G-Master (with G-Sync, if that matters), the other (good) monitor is an older HP screen.

Is this a driver issue? Something else? Any help is appreciated!